# Are planets without large moons getting weaker magnetic fields?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, planets, satellites

Recently I read a study according to which in order for a terrestrial planet to have a magnetic field, a sufficiently large satellite is needed, since the satellite's gravitational influence melts the core of the planet. Is this a common property? And can this conclusion be trusted?

References:

- C. Davies, J. Mound, ["Life on Earth: why we may have the Moon’s now defunct magnetic field to thank for it"](https://theconversation.com/life-on-earth-why-we-may-have-the-moons-now-defunct-magnetic-field-to-thank-for-it-148111), *The Conversation*, Oct. 15, 2020.
- B. Smith, ["No Moon, no magnetic field, no life on Earth"](https://cosmosmagazine.com/geoscience/no-moon-no-magnetic-field-no-life-earth-study/), *Cosmos Magazine*, Apr. 1, 2016.

Comment: Mercury has an intrinsic magnetic field but no major orbiting satellite.  The moons of Jupiter, Saturn, Neptune, and Uranus may be large (i.e., some are comparable to Mercury in size) but they are tiny compared to the object they orbit.  The Earth's moon is unusually large compared to its planetary host.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to say this argument is fundamentally flawed as evidenced by [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)), which has an intrinsic magnetic field but no natural satellites.

The moon [Ganymede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(moon)) also has an intrinsic magnetic field but doesn't have any of its own satellites either.

[Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars) no longer has an intrinsic magnetic field but it has two satellites, Phobos and Deimos.

In short, no I do not trust their conclusion if your representation of it is accurate.

Comment: I fully agree with your first paragraph about Mercury. But Ganymede gets tidal heating from Jupiter, and Phobos & Deimos are too small to cause tidal effects.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Oh I know, but I was criticizing the strict phrasing of the claim as reported by the OP.  My guess is that the authors were slightly more careful and argued that tidal forces are necessary, not merely that planetary bodies need to have their own satellite(s).